# syntax error near unexpected token `fi'

Tags: bash

I am beginner in bash 
I am unable to figure out what is wrong with this code .

```
#!/bin/bash

j=0
k=1

for i in $1
do
    echo "tile-"+$j +"-" +"$k"
    (($j=$j+1))
    if [ "$j" == "6" ]  then
        $j=0
        (($k=$k+1))
    fi
done
```

Comment: You're missing a `;` or newline before `then`.

Comment: ...and I guess `$j=0` should be `j=0`. Also, you can get rid of the `$` inside `(( ))`.

Comment: yup ,now its working thanks a lot for quick reply  :)

Comment: @NishantVerma You do *not* concat strings with `+` but: `echo "hello""world"` and you *should* quote all variable substitutions unless you are 100% sure that you shouldn't

Answer (score 1):

Just as `for` and `do`, `if` and `then` are two different (although related) constructs and should be separated by a command terminator, either `;` or a line feed :

```
if [ "$j" == "6" ]; then
    [...]
fi

if [ "$j" == "6" ]
then
    [...]
fi
```